# Azure Template VNet with 4 subnets

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I have been trying to manipulate this template, located at: [https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vnet-two-subnets/azuredeploy.json] Here is the original JSON:

```css
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "VNet1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "VNet name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnet1Prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 1 Prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Subnet1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 1 Name"
      }
    },
    "subnet2Prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.1.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 2 Prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnet2Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Subnet2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 2 Name"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1Prefix')]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet2Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet2Prefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I did is add 2 extra subnets using the CIDR Range of 192.168.50.0/24 for the Address Range.
For the 4 subnets I used the following Range: 192.168.50.0/27

See below for the JSON used:

---

```css
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "TestVNet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "VNet name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.50.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnet1Prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.50.0/27",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 1 Prefix - Public"
      }
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Public-SN1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 1 - Public"
      }
    },
    "subnet2Prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.50.32/27",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 2 Prefix - Public"
      }
    },
    "subnet2Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Public-SN2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 2 - Public"
      }
    },
    "subnet3Prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.50.96/27",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 3 Prefix - Private"
      },
    "subnet3Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Private-SN1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 3 - Private"
      }
    },
    "subnet4Prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.50.128/27",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet 4 Prefix - Private"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1Prefix')]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet2Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet2Prefix')]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet3Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet3Prefix')]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet4Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet4Prefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I run it in Azure Powershell it fails everytime.

Commands:

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name TestVNet -Location uksouth

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name TestVNet -ResourceGroupName TestVNet -TemplateFile vnet_4subnets.json

Error:

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'parameters', line 112, position 2.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name TestVNet -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], JsonReaderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

Comment: It looks like your subnet3Prefix metadata is lacking a closing curly brace. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Oh wow, I have been staring at this for hours! thankyou! I knew it was simple but I have been staring at it for hours!!

Comment: to avoid such trouble in the future, try to paste your code into an IDE with JSON support (e.g. SublimeText or IntelliJ) - this would have shown you the problem immediately.